# Best way to do correlation analysis of data which is 1 or 0 python

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I have this example data

```
point_1 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]
point_2 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1]
point_3 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]
values =  [1900,1700,1800,1300,1600,1400,1900,1300,1800,1400,900,1200]

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'point_1': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1],
                         'point_2': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1],
                         'point_3': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
                         'values':  [1900,1700,1800,1300,1600,1400,1900,1300,1800,1400,900,1200]})

import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(dataframe.corr())
```

What is a good way to find relationships between them?
I have tried a correlation plot and it doesn't really give me much insight. Please let me know your thoughts on what  I can try.

Comment: What is your expected result (or insight) for you example data?

Comment: To understand if values is affected by the 3 points and if there is any way or seeing if it e.g. one point is 1 and the others are 0 then does it mean the values will be lower or higher for example

Answer (score 0):

Import libraires

```
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings

d = defaultdict(LabelEncoder)

df_temp=dataframe.astype(str) #read in object format

fit = df_temp.apply(lambda x: d[x.name].fit_transform(x))

corr = fit.corr()

corr['total_amounts'].sort_values(ascending=False)
plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
sns.heatmap(corr,annot=True,cmap='coolwarm')

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zedNK.png #you can see the image here.
![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zedNK.png) #i don't know how to display the image

corr['values'] #here you can see positive and negative corr. 
#you may ignore most neg. in original dataframe for further decision making such as regression testing or training purposes

point_1   -0.201688
point_2   -0.504219
point_3   -0.475923
values     1.000000
```